# NSButton, binding question

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsbutton

I am trying a cocoa application with core-data. The application contains an entity: UsefulUrl with attribute: url. The entered urls are displayed in table view.

I am able to insert, modify and delete the entered urls from table via cocoa bindings (NSArrayController).

Now,

> I want to open the urls of selected
>   rows in browser, on click of a button, using cocoa bindings.

I think I can do it via button's bindings: Action Invocation - Argument/ Target, but I could not make it working.

Can anyone suggest me exactly how to do it or some useful url?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right... in the argument binding pane I binded the url of UsefulUrl and in target I binded the selector gotoUrl: in my controller class. In gotoUrl method I used NSWorkspace method to open the link in default browser and it is working as intended :)